# React-Bootstrap Radio Button not checking when clicked, but is rendering value

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

**SOLVED**:

**It was a problem in the main container styles in the main files.**

---

When i try to click a **React-Bootstrap Radio Button**, it doesn't check when clicked, but in the console log, it renders value.

If i remove the react-bootstrap part, and have normal HTML radio buttons, it works normally.

This is the main code:

```
    <Form>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label htmlFor="currentlyBuying">Are you currently buying this home:</Form.Label>
        <Form.Check
          type="radio"
          name="currentlyBuying"
          label="Yes"
          value='true'
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <Form.Check
          type="radio"
          name="currentlyBuying"
          label="No"
          value='false'
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button onClick={back}>Back</Button> 
      <Button onClick={next}>Next</Button>
    </Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to provide a state for value props in radio button. You have given static value='false'.
It need to be change or toggle in handleChange func.

Comment: the handleChange function is in another main file, it retrieves the value prop, and i have more files like this because it is a multistep form.

Comment: But you are not changing the value of  Form.check component.